# How do I scale a control from the center?

Tags: godot, godot4

Is there a code-free way to dynamically set the pivot_offset of a label?

I'm attempting to animate a label and any attempt to change the scale makes it scale from the top left corner.  If I manually set the pivot_offset to size/2 (which isn't dynamic), the scaling looks "janky" compared to not having it set at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question, especially what you mean by "janky" or "dynamic"?
Maybe put the [`label`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_label.html) inside a [`Node2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html) and animate it's `scale`?

[image]

The output looks like this:

[image]